# Iterating through a lists of lists and appending to a new list

Tags: python

I have the following structure,

```
lists_ = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

within each list there are variables i'd like to access iterate and pass into a list.

```
new_lists_ = [a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1] # empty individual lists.
```

so from `lists_` i'd like to acess all the variables in `a` and pass these into `a1` with what I'm hoping is a simple one liner.(however I prefer readability!)

my own attemp :

```
for list_ in lists_:
    for new_list_ in new_lists_:
        for l in list_:
            new_list.append(l)
```

^ this adds all the items to all the lists so not what I'm after.

naturally, I could access each list individually and iterate this way, but I feel like this isn't good practice. I'm unsure if the above is good or bad practice so any advice is appreciated.

(also my first non pandas question, so I guess this is a milestone..?!)

Comment: what will each element in new_lists_ look like? i.e., how will a1 be different from a?

Comment: I will run some functions over it to change the data structure (the above is a simple version) but I want to keep the original lists is that clear? so `ABC` in `a`  may become `123` in `a1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```py
from copy import deepcopy

new_lists_ = deepcopy(lists_)
```

> A *deep copy* constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts *copies* into it of the objects found in the original.

---

Or going with your method, maybe you should iterate indices instead:

```py
for i in range(len(lists_)):
    for elem in lists_[i]:
        new_lists_[i].append(elem)
```

Or as requested, a one-liner:

```py
new_lists_ = [[elem for elem in lists_[i]] for i in range(len(lists_))]
```

**Note:** that in the first method, of the explicit loop, **you have to make sure** that all sub-lists are initialized or you will get an `IndexError`. In the second method of the list-comprehension we simply create a new list.

Comment: could also use the enumerate() method to grab both index and nested list in one go, rather than the outer loop plus inner loop for index and nested list, respectively.

Comment: You can also use unpacking `new_lists_ = [[*inner_list] for inner_list in lists_]`.

Comment: @cptwonton You can't avoid nested loops as you're iterating a nested list. The outer loop is for iterating through the nested lists and the inner loop is for iterating each nested list. How can you avoid that?

Comment: @cptwonton I still don't follow. Let's say I do `for i, sub in enumerate(lists_):`. What now? I have a sub list an its index in the main list. How will I go over its elements?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I uhh... don't think you can haha. Nested loops are necessary. enumerate() is just an alternative. I would edit my first comment if I could

Comment: you, sir, are a legend, thank you so much, took me a while to figure it out but this helped me greatly.

Comment: @cptwonton haha all good. I just thought of another fun alternative which is using `zip`, but as you can see there are many and I can't (shouldn't) put all in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Nested loops are things you generally want to avoid.

If you really wanted to stick with a super-uber pythonic way of doing this with nested loops, this should work:

```
new_lists_ = []

for list_ in lists_:
  new_list_ = []
  for l in list_:
    #some computation on l, stored in stuff, and appended to new_list_
    new_list_.append(stuff)
  new_lists_.append(new_list_)
```

But this is awkward to read and follow when debugging.

One way to help debug would be to use the enumerate(item) method in your python loops.

But an even better way, in my opinion, is to split this processing (and nested looping) off into another method, like so:

```
def some_function(list_):
  #do some stuff here, store in processed_list_
  processed_list_ = []
  for l in list_:
    processed_list_.append(l) #you'll want to modify l, of course
  return processed_list_

new_lists_ = []

for list_ in lists_:
  new_lists_.append(some_function(list_))
```

much simpler, I think.

If you're following some special style guide, then ignore this, but I would also recommend rethinking how you're naming variables, specifically with your appending a "_" underscore to every variable name. Following some sort of popular python style guide, like the google one [here](http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html), is a good idea for two main reasons:

1. it's easier for others to read, as they're familiar with it already
2. it's a popular style guide BECAUSE it's naturally easy to read

Comment: I really wanted to green tick this as it was more helpful but I couldn't figure out how to implement my function into this but I will keep trying. Thanks for the advice I will start using a proper style guide!

Answer (score -1):

I would utilize the while loop in order to iterate over a list of lists. Here is an example but instead of the print statement you could alter list elements.

```
a = [1,2,3] #example elements
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]
lists_ = [a,b,c] 


new_lists_ = [] 
i = 0
while i < len(lists_):
        for x in lists_[i]:
            print(x) 
        i+=1
```

this will output 1-9 as each element has been looked over.